# Como adicionar JQuery no Electron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

Sou desenvolvedor web, eu já tentei metódos em um post inglês, Mas... nenhum funciona, eu quero adicionar *JQuery* no *electon*.

Eu já usei esse sem `window.$` não funciona.

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>
```

Eu tentei com `window.$` tava funcionando mas parou de funcionar por algum motivo desconhecido...

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' onclick='window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;'></script>
```

Alguém sabe algum *script* para fazer *JQuery* funcionar?

Eu quero deixar ele no meu `main.js` (index.js) em vez de deixar em uma página web se possível. Se não dar, eu deixo na página web mesmo.

Comment: Já tentou algo como `const $ = require('jquery')`?

Answer (score 5):

Você precisa usar o [*node* para instalar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery) o jQuery para que possa usa-lo no server-side.

Veja abaixo:

```
npm install jQuery
```

Em seguida basta você incluir o pacote do jQuery (como [sugerido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/259633/como-adicionar-jquery-no-electron#comment532592_259633) pelo Anderson Carlos Woss):

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
```

No exemplo de ilustração que segue abaixo, eu inclui o pacote no arquivo `index.html`, entretanto, você pode incluir no seu `main.js` ou em uma janela separada.

```
<script>
    // You can also require other files to run in this process
    require('./renderer.js')
    var $ = require('jQuery');

    // Pode usar o jQuery normalmente agora.
    $(document).ready(
        function() 
        { 
            $("<h1>Test jQuery</h1>").appendTo('body');
        }
    );
</script>
```